# Should EasyMock be used to mock only external services?

Tags: junit, easymock, in-memory-database

I have a question concerning the use of EasyMock in junits. We have configured a framework for junits which uses inmemory derby database and EasyMock to test our service project. We use in memory derby for dao layer completely. The question arises on weather to use  EasyMock completely or easymock and derby together in the service layer. Below is the scenario :

```
    //class under test is in user-service project
    class ServiceClassUnderTest {
             IUserService userService; 
             IAddressService addressService; 

             public Address getUsersAddress(String id) {
                        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
                        // some logic goes here
                        Address address = addressService.getAddresdByUser(user);
                       // some validations goes here
                        return address;
             }
      }
```

The class under test is in user-service project  and so is the IUserService interface. While IAddressService interface is in address-service project used as a dependency in user-service project.

Now the problem is in the change of approach suggested by some colleagues.

### Approach we used to follow

Prepare test data for userService as its in the same project and mock addressService as its part of a dependency project and we might not have much idea about its behaviour and table structure

Advantage : cleaner approach as we have mimimal code for mocking and test data is in separate sql files

### Suggested approach

Mock all services irrespective of its being in the same project or part of a dependency project

Disadvantage : more mocking relevant code then actual test related code, making it difficult to maintain and compromises readability.

---

The code example given is to only explain the scenario where as in real project we have a lot more complex structure with several service beans in a single class.

Could you please give me your suggestions on which approach is better and why considering the arguments provided by me for both approaches ??

Comment: Hi all, could you please give me your feedback on the approach that should be followed

Answer (score 1):

A definitive is hard without have the complete big picture. Assuming you really want unit tests, I usually do this:

- Test only the query done to the DB with an actual DB
- Mock everything that is used by my tested class.

This "everything" should be no more than 3 or 4 dependencies. Otherwise, I will refactor until I get something that is readable.

Having more test code than production code is normal.

If I end up having trivial code in my tested method, I just don't test it. However, a test can also be used to document. So this is a blurry line.